# ASP.NET MVC How X-Editable send all form input value to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, x-editable

Im Currently Building ASP.Net with MVC. I have a form that consist of several input.

[image]

I want to use x-editable UI to prevent user from accidentally changing some input that they dont want, just the UI, no AjAX etc, the form will submitted with submit button. I try to add X-Editable to that input field.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emp_nik').editable();
});
```

```
<div class="form-group margin0">
            <label for="emp_nik" class="control-label col-md-4 left">Employee Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-3 left">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.X.EmpName, new { Id = "emp_nik", @Class = "form-control input-sm", Value = Html.DisplayFor(model => model.X.EmpName) })
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when i click it and input value in X-Editable popup form, the input value remain unchanged. How to change form input field value with X-Editable? Thank You